# Adjust time format in Laravel?

Tags: html, laravel-5

This is my code:

```
 {{ date ('M-d-Y',strtotime($page->created_at)) }}
```

The date shows up like this: May-23-2018

How can I modify the code so the date shows up like this: Posted on May 23, 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All character meaning : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

You can change symbols in your format how ever you like as long as you have correct characters(from table).

```
<span>Posted on {{ date('M d, Y',strtotime($page->created_at)) }}</span>
```

Also Laravel comes wihh Carbon extension for DateTime and is easy to use for working with dates: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in 2 ways:

1. Simple way: Have 3 variables for a date, month and year and create the string the way you want.
2. Use date_format: Check https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.I hope it will help you.

```
 {{ date("F jS, Y", strtotime($page->created_at)) }}
```